# Interpolation in PHP for chef automation

Tags: php, ruby, wordpress, chef-infra, chef-solo

Hi I am using chef for deployment automation of a wordpress site where in I need to read `database`, `host`, `username` and `password` from my `shared.yml` for `wp-config.php` so I am trying below code in my template file

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', '"<%= @database %>"');
define('DB_USER', '"<%= @username %>"');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '"<%= @password %>"');
define('DB_HOST', '"<% @host %>"');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
?>
```

however the interpolation isn't taking place in where it should take actual values that are defined in `_shared.yml`.  My attributes in chef looks like below.

```
default[:example_wp][:database][:host]          = ""
default[:example_wp][:database][:adapter]       = "mysql2"
default[:example_wp][:database][:database]      = "wordpress"
default[:example_wp][:database][:username]      = "wordpress"
default[:example_wp][:database][:password]      = ""
```

Can someone help with interpolation that I am trying.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems odd to be single double quoting that. `'"<%= @database %>"'` vs `"<%= @database %>"`. Also what is `@` there for should that be `$` I cannot find anything on that symbol.

Comment: @nerdlyist Actually that's a ruby syntax to denote that it's ruby variable which is represented by `<% @variable %>`

Comment: Is this a PHP file or a ruby file? How are you parsing the yaml?

Comment: This is a php file but it's a template file where in you can manage your ruby variables.

Comment: I am not sure that makes sense if you are in php you need to use php

Answer (score 0):

So a few issues, the first is you need to make sure you're passing the attributes to the template resource:

```
template '/whatever/wp-config.php' do
  # Other stuff here ...
  variables node[:example_wp][:database].to_hash
end
```

The second is that as pointed out in the comments, you probably don't mean to have those extra double quotes in the template or the rendered value will look like `'"wordpress"'`.

Third, I'm not sure what you mean by the `shared.yml` part, are these node attributes or are you trying to read them from a local file, and if the latter then where did the file come from?

Comment: `_shared.yml` is node attribute file where I am passing all the details of database connection which i want to use in recipe. Also I am using template resource here. So I am not worried about it. What I am concerned about is my ruby variables are not getting interpolated in php config file which is a template file ultimately.